# Setting maximum number of sign-ups in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms, registration

We use Google Forms to manage a large school event in which each activity requires sign-up using a separate form. We have a maximum number of students per activity. How do we 
“close” the sign up once the maximum has been reached? Is there a way to then automatically submit data to a wait list?

Answer (score 2):

With this little script, you can easily pre-set the number of responses.

### Code

```
function closeForm() {
  // get active form
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // retrieve number of responses thusfar
  var responses = form.getResponses().length;

  // set close message
  var msg = "Maximum number of respondents has been reached";

  // set max 
  var maxResponse = 3;

  // do the math
  if(responses >= maxResponse) {
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false).setCustomClosedFormMessage(msg);
  }
}
```

### Note

In this particular case the number of responses is limited to three. Add the script, in the form editor under *Tools>Script editor* (same as in a Google Spreadsheet). Now the script needs to be activated, each time a submission is being made. In the script editor, under *Resources*, select the script to run *On form submit*.

[image]

Comment: 4.5 years later, the code still works :D

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is! Look at [these instructions](http://www.youpd.org/content/google-forms-pd-sign-session-caps-using-formranger-script-simple-formula) from Lise Galuga.
I have modified the code and written about it in [this blogpost](http://www.trendmatcher.nl/2014/01/google-form-met-maximum-aantal.html), but that's in Dutch;-)

Comment: They still have the Yeas and the Nays in the senate, but Dutch isn't really a global language anymore.